# Electrical Standards for Exposed DC Connections

Tags: dc, standard, low-voltage, iec

We are trying to make a slide lock connection between two parts and thus need to have some sort of connector between them.

I am wondering if anyone is aware of a IEC standard relevant for connecting a 'Low Voltage' system to each other (I would be looking at a connectors rated for 100-400V). I can seemingly find a bunch of standards relating to low voltage AC connections however not DC. I am sure I cannot have four exposed terminals at 300VDC that I just slide together but I can't see a standard that clarifies what I can and can't do.

Can anyone advise a place to look or a standard?

Comment: Are these contacts going to be exposed (i.e. touchable) while energized?

Comment: No, I imagine this would be a no go. The workflow is that these two parts have to be connected first and then they would be connected to mains (once connected as a single unit).

Comment: There are a few connectors that have ratings for this. SHV comes to mind. There are some high-voltage touch-safe connectors in Anderson's PowerPole line, though I'm not sure whether they go up to 400 V or not. Cal Test makes some extremely recessed banana plugs that they claim are good to a few kV. Standard shrouded banana plugs should be usable for 400 V.

Comment: Thanks @Hearth, I have come across connectors that can do the job but I want to understand what standard they are abiding by and that is what I'm struggling to find.

Comment: The two main questions which spring to mind are 1) what power levels you are talking about (max current)?, 2) what kind of interlock exists on the connector / supply circuit?  Peak current will obviously have a very large impact on the physical size of connector you need, but in addition opening a live high-power 300V DC circuit will be "exciting", with very significant connector arcing (as you don't have the 100-120 zero current periods with 50Hz/60Hz AC).  If the connector can be pulled apart under load, you will need a setup with something like a shorter pilot pin for supply interlock.

Comment: Worth talking to a manufacturer or distributor of power connectors, they'll have application engineers who can advise and knowledge of the relevant standards.